# Referencing jquery in javascript called from ribbon

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am writing some Javascript to call a web service and display a progress bar whilst the web service call is in progress.

The javascript is being triggered by a button on the ribbon.

I would like to use jQuery to implement this functionality - but jQuery is not loaded by Dynamics CRM and the entity form is not loaded yet.

Is there a simple way to specify that my Javascript method being used on the ribbon has a dependency on jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to load some JS library before yours main library just add Java Script function tag to yours actions into the command definition with function name isNaN.

```xml
<Actions>
    <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="isNaN" Library="$webresource:neededLibrary.js" />  
    <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="myFunction" Library="$webresource:myLibrary.js" />
</Actions>
```